# How to check if a value is a table

Tags: lua, lua-table

So simply as the name suggests... You can't say like

```
3[7] --> Attempt to index a number value
"fpp"[7] --> Attempt to index a string value
```

I know the function `type()`, but I am trying to avoid it, because it's slow.

```
if(type({}) == "table") ...
if(string.sub(tostring({}),1,5) == "table")...

function ArrayCount(arArr)
  if(not arArr) then return 0 end
  if(not (type(arArr) == "table")) then return 0 end
  if(not (arArr and arArr[1])) then return return 0 end
  local Count = 1
  while(arArr[Count]) do Count = Count + 1 end
  return (Count - 1)
end

ArrayCount(3)
ArrayCount("I am a string!")
```

Comment: Define *slow*.... Also, why do you need this test?

Comment: Put the code in your question instead of comments.

Answer (score 4):

The `type` function is not slow. Update your function to simply:

```
function ArrayCount(arArr)
  if type( arArr ) ~= "table" then return 0 end
  return #arArr - 1
end
```

Comment: The ops count incremented until nil so the -1 was to give the correct length but isn't needed here.

Comment: Yes it is, as I am coding a Gmod tool, the type function was extended to support the extra Game Lua types. Trust me it's slow